# Why is the name of the novel and the movie First Men in the Moon?

Tags: first-men-in-the-moon

Why is the name of the novel and movie *First Men **in** the Moon*?

As far as I know it's grammatically incorrect. The preposition of celestial bodies is **on**. For example, Where on Earth is this city located? Or The aliens live on the planet.

So why did they choose *in* here? Was it with a purpose?

Comment: "*After escaping, the two men discover that the sphere, still containing Kate, has been dragged into the **underground city***"

Comment: Oh, I didn't take that into account.

Comment: I assumed it was based on the common phrase ["the man in the moon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_in_the_Moon). Doing some quick googling I couldn't find anything to verify that, but I did find reference to a proto-SF story called ["The Man in the Moone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_Moone) that might have influenced Wells' story in certain ways. As Valorum notes they do travel beneath the surface in the novel, but I doubt Wells chose the title solely because he wanted to alert readers to this plot point in advance.

Comment: https://go.gale.com/ps/i.do?id=GALE%7CA619741572&sid=googleScholar&v=2.1&it=r&linkaccess=abs&issn=00145483&p=LitRC&sw=w&userGroupName=anon%7Eb8348299&aty=open-web-entry suggests that it was supposed to be a "man in the moon" parallel.

Comment: I would guess (without knowing anything about the story) that it was both. It evokes the familiar phrase "the man in the moon", and yet it is also an accurate description of what's in the story, despite the unusual preposition! The overlap makes it almost humourous.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Looks like the full paper is available [here](https://jenkelleywalker.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Shooting-for-the-Moon.pdf), I guess you're referring to the brief comment on p. 20 that "As the curious preposition in the title reveals (aside from a strained joke on the Man in the Moon), Wells envisions a hollow moon for his work"? The author doesn't make clear if this is just a speculation or if there is documentary evidence that Wells intended this "strained joke", though.

Comment: Ah. I only had a cached excerpt from the search results, and it looked more definite from that. I stand corrected.

Comment: Wait til you find out that they don't go 20,000 leagues deep in "20,000 Leagues Under the Sea".

Comment: @JonathanZ Of course the 20,000 leagues in *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea* wasn't a measure of depth. It was a measure of distance the submarine went inside the sea.

Comment: They spend a lot of the novel actually *in* the moon...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The story (and its source novel) are specifically about a group of adventurers who travel *inside* the moon, not merely to its surface.

> “The air is denser. We must be some depths—a mile even, we may
> be—inside the moon.”
>
> “We never thought of a world inside the moon.”
>
> “No.”
>
> “How could we?”
>
> “We might have done. Only one gets into habits of mind.”
>
> <sub><sup>[H.G. Wells - The First Men in the Moon](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1013/pg1013-images.html)</sup></sub>

The original movie poster illustrates this rather splendidly.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Other answers point out that in the story, the men go inside the Moon. However, in addition to that, I believe the use of 'on' for celestial bodies wasn't so well established in 1900 when the story was written, with 'in' being an acceptable alternative.

In his previous book, the War of the Worlds (1898), H. G. Wells uses both "in Mars" and "on Mars". ("On Mars" appears 5 times, "upon Mars" 5 times and "in Mars" 3 times, at least in the version on [project Guttenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/36/36-h/36-h.htm).) For example, in chapter 3 he writes "In spite of Ogilvy, I still believed that there were men in Mars." So I think for Wells at that time, "in the Moon" would have been synonymous with "on the Moon" and didn't necessarily have to refer to being inside the Moon.

Indeed, in [The First Men in the Moon](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1013/pg1013-images.html) itself, Wells uses the phrase "in the Moon" before the men are taken inside the Moon. (In chapter XI: "It filled me with a curiously benevolent satisfaction that there was such good food in the moon." They are still on the surface at this point.)

As further evidence I present [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Mars%2Con+Mars%2Cin+Venus%2Con+Venus%2Cin+the+Moon%2Con+the+Moon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for "in Mars", "on Mars", "in Venus", "on Venus", "in the Moon", "on the Moon":

[image]

The Moon ones are a bit conflated because "in the Moon" appears in the phrase "man in the Moon", which is why I included the others as well. You can see that initially the "in" and "on" forms both occur, with the "on" forms not really taking over until around the 1950s, when spaceflight started to become a thing.

Clicking through for examples, one finds plenty of sentences like "...the work of an intelligent race, if any such race could possibly have been developed under the adverse conditions which exist **in Mars**" or "fogs and mists prevail **in Mars**," so "in" does refer to the surface, at least some of the time. I suspect people thought of being "in" a planet as similar to being in a country.

One can also find several other books from 1900 or before that include "in the Moon" in their title, including [The Man in the Moone (1638)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_Moone), which features a man who lands on the Moon but doesn't go inside it, as well as [The Marvellous and Incredible Adventures of Charles Thunderbolt, in the Moon (1851)](https://www.google.co.jp/books/edition/The_Marvellous_and_Incredible_Adventures/dcABAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) and [Adventures in the Moon And Other Worlds (1836)](https://www.google.co.jp/books/edition/Adventures_in_the_Moon/gFc8AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). (I haven't checked to see if the characters in the other two books go inside the Moon or not but suspect they don't.)

So in summary, I suspect that to a reader in 1900 "the first men in the Moon" wouldn't have sounded odd and would have meant the same as "the first men on the Moon".

However, by 1964 when the movie came out the language had changed a bit and "in" would have been seen as referring specifically to the interior, which is presumably why the movie poster in Valorum's answer emphasises that aspect so strongly.

Comment: And there is a blaze around the word "in" in that poster. And the phrase itself is going inside the Moon (or it came out of it)

Comment: Google Ngrams supports various operators for combining terms, so you can [exclude "man in the moon"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Mars%2Con+Mars%2Cin+Venus%2Con+Venus%2Cin+the+Moon%2Cman+in+the+moon%2C%28in+the+Moon+-+man+in+the+moon%29%2Con+the+Moon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Wells uses "in Mars" because the Martians don't live on the surface.

Comment: @Valorum that doesn't match my memory of the book. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: In any case it doesn't match the contexts where he uses it. In "In spite of Ogilvy, I still believed that there were men in Mars", even if the Martians live underground, the protagonist couldn't possibly know that at this point in the story; and when he writes "Apparently the vegetable kingdom in Mars, instead of having green for a dominant colour, is of a vivid blood-red tint", this seems to strongly hint at vegetation growing on the surface, thus explaining why Mars is red in colour when seen from space.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Martians don't live underground in Wells' original novel. In modern adaptations they might be portrayed as living underground, because modern audiences know what the surface of Mars is really like, but in 1900 that wasn't known (neither to the public nor to science) and all planets tended to be portrayed as having air, water and vegetation just like Earth does. Wells talks about Mars as having shrinking oceans and growing ice caps, but the impression is of an Earth-like world that is gradually becoming inhospitable, not a dead world whose inhabitants live underground.

Comment: @N.Virgo - Wells' story ["The Crystal Egg"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crystal_Egg) (available in full [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/27365/27365-h/27365-h.htm#Page_1)) may be set in the same "universe" as War of the Worlds, with a crystal that allows a man on Earth to view scenes of Mars' surface, he sees some flying Martians and "on the causeways and terraces, large-headed creatures similar to the greater winged flies, but wingless, were visible, hopping busily upon their hand-like tangle of tentacles." (he speculates that the wings seen on some Martians may be artificial)

Comment: @Hypnosifl indeed, he uses "in Mars" there too: "I believe the crystal on the mast in Mars and the crystal egg of Mr. Cave's to be in some physical, but at present quite inexplicable, way *en rapport*..." (and the mast he refers to is very clearly on the surface and outdoors)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The OP is reading way too much into the preposition "in".

Answer (score 8):

In his novel "First Men in the Moon", H. G. Wells describes the moon's surface as experiencing a four-week cycle of growth and freezing: during the lunar day, the natives are able to cultivate the surface, but their homes are underground, where they are protected from the moon's cryogenically cold nights.

The 1964 film version portrayed the lunar surface more realistically, as always exposed to open space. (The film does not show how the Selenites survived on the surface when they captured the Cavorite sphere).

The novel is titled "First Men in the Moon" because the earthling characters were captured and taken inside the moon, where they are chained up.

Link to a Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Men_in_the_Moon

[image]